# Проблема c анимацией, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

вот сайт с анимацией в headere как так сделать а то я 5 часов убил,  а только не на шаг не приблизился
www.creative-knight.com/
вот скрин еще [image: анимированная фигура]

Также там первая картинка как уходит вниз также подскажите как сделать ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/raubaca/pen/VjLbgO - пожалуй наглядно, думаю получится у вас?

Comment: спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: 1) Спасибо скажите если знаете как inscape получить svg-код чтобы вставить html ? 2) там при скролле фоновое изображение уходит вниз скажите как сделать если знаете?

Comment: 1) ПОльзуюсь программами от adobe - ХЗ как работает ink
2) У изображения transform3d задаётся посредством JS при скролле

Comment: спасибо, выручили !!! (  а код js скажите при скролле :)) ?   )

Comment: http://www.creative-knight.com/js/global.min.js там ищите parallaxMe

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: 1) изначально только корзина появляется потом левый верхним линии вырисовывается а потом появляется надпись. Далее аналогично поочерёдно
2)Потом правый нижний, потом лев низ,и вверх
https://disk.yandex.ru/client/disk?display=normal&groupBy=none&order=1&sort=name&view=icons&wasAsideAnimated=false&typeClustering=geo&action=null&idAlbum=undefined&idApp=client&dialog=slider&idDialog=%2Fdisk%2FSlice_1%20(1).png

Comment: Сможете такую анимацию сделать ?

Comment: Ссылка на яндекс не работает.
Чтобы найти того кто сделает такую анимацию вам необходимо обратиться на специальную площадку фриланса.
Здесь же могу помочь если покажете ваш код и что не работает